# Difference in ATP synthesis in mitochondria and chloroplast

Tags: cell-biology, mitochondria, thermodynamics, chloroplasts

The mechanism of ATP synthesis in mitochondria and chloroplasts are almost the same, but there is a big difference: the f1 particle in mitochondria uses 2 H+ ions to synthesize one ATP, whereas in chloroplasts the f1 particle uses 3 H+ ions for the same. What make the difference?

Comment: Any reference for f1 particle uses 2 protons?

Comment: It was mentioned in my text book, local  publication.

Comment: see this http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/3186/given-atp-synthases-structure-how-can-3-33-protons-ultimately-synthesize-one-a

Comment: Does this mean that the ATP synthase works same in both mitochondria and chloroplast. But what I have read is that 1 NADPH in mitochondria is capable of sending 6 H+ ions in to the space between the two membranes of mitochondrial. And it obviously produces 3ATP , so 2H+ for one ATP.

Comment: 1 NADPH does not produce exactly 3 ATP

Comment: Also NADH is used for atp synthesis not NADPH, and 1NADH pumps 10 protons , not 6 protons, provide any reference please.

Comment: This may help:http://www.madsci.org/posts/archives/1999-01/915551393.Bc.r.html

Comment: Reference: one of our coaching institute's book (akash).

Comment: So the book mentioned it wrong I will intimate them the same, and thanks for the link.